# about Java BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm new to Java and just code a program with BigInteger.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  BigInteger n = new BigInteger("5");
  BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2");
  while (lesserOrEqual(i,n) {
    System.out.println("n.mod(i) = "+n.mod(i));
    if (n.mod(i) == ZERO) {
      n = n.divide(i);
    }
    else {
      i.add(ONE);
  }
  System.out.println("n = "+n);
  System.out.println("i = "+i);
}


public static boolean lesserOrEqual(BigInteger m, BigInteger n) `{
  if (m.compareTo(n) == -1 || m.compareTo(n) == 0)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

ZERO and ONE are defined of the type BigInteger 0, 1, respectively.

I want "i=2" to divide "n=5", if "n mod i == 0", else "i++", until "n" to be lesser or equal to "i".

I think the output must be

```
n.mod(i) = 1
n = 5
i = 3
n.mod(i) = 2
n = 5
i = 4
n.mod(i) = 1
n = 5
i = 5
n.mod(i) = 0
n = 1
i = 5
```

and with the equivalent code with primitive type int, I have the result as expected.

but this with BigInteger goes to infinite loop

```
n.mod(i) = 1
n = 5
i = 2
...
```

Does anyone know why it is so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The BigInteger class represents integers as immutable objects.

There are two points here.

1. Don't use `==` to test if two `BigInteger`s are equal
2. To change the value of a BigInteger variable you must do `i = i.add(ONE);` and not just `i.add(ONE);`.

The reason not to use `==` to compare `BigInteger`s is because instead of checking for numerical equality you are checking that they are the same object in memory.

Consider with `String`s.

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";

String x = a + b;
String y = "ab";
```

In the above example `x.equals(y)` is true because they contain the same number of characters in exactly the same order. However, `x == y` is not true because they are different objects in memory.

The reason you need to to assign the result of arithmetic operations to a variable is because BigInteger is immutable. Thus arithmetic operations cannot change the value of the object it is operating on, but it can create a new BigInteger (which it returns). Which is why you must assign the result of the arithmetic operation to the variable you want it saved in.

As an aside a shortcut for your lesserThanOrEqual to is this.

```
boolean result = m.compareTo(n) <= 0;
```

Basically

- `m == n` becomes `m.compareTo(n) == 0`
- `m != n` becomes `m.compareTo(n) != 0`
- `m < n` becomes `m.compareTo(n) < 0`
- `m > n` becomes `m.compareTo(n) > 0`
- `m <= n` becomes `m.compareTo(n) <= 0`
- `m >= n` becomes `m.compareTo(n) >= 0`

Comment: Thkan you for the detailed explain!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
i.add(ONE);
```

But you should do this:

```
i = i.add(ONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

both of the above answers are right.  They are not telling you, however, that BigInteger instances are **immutable**.  That means they don't change once set.  That is why you need to always assign the result of a transformation...

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the result that gets returned from `i.add(ONE)`. It's giving you a `BigInteger` object containing the desired value, but you're dropping it on the floor instead of assigning it to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`i.add(ONE)` has to be reassigned: `i = i.add(ONE)`